# How to restrict parameter value based on keys of generic parameter?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I've got a simplified example of what I want to achieve below. I have a class B with generic parameter "T" - I want to restrict the allowed value of some method parameter to only those values which match the keys of the parameter "T".

In my smooth brain, what I have below ought to do what I think I want. But I just get the errors I've put on the lines there.

What I want is that it would restrict the values of calling something like the "foo" method to only those that match the T parameter, so `b.foo("asdf")` would be fine, but `b.foo("qwerty")` would not ("qwerty" not in keyof A).

Any help on how to progress would be appreciated.

```
interface A {
    asdf: string;
}

type Names<X extends A> = X extends A ? keyof X : never;

class B<T extends A> {
    foo(N: Names<T>) {

    }

    baz(n: Names<T>) {
        this.foo("asdf"); // Argument of type '"asdf"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Names<T>'.ts(2345)
        this.foo("qwerty"); // expect an error here, but not the other ones


        this.foo(n); // fine?
    }
}

interface C extends A {
    qwerty: string;
}

class D<T extends C> extends B<T> {
    bar() {
        this.foo("asdf"); // Argument of type '"asdf"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Names<T>'.ts(2345)

        this.foo("qwerty"); // Argument of type '"qwerty"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Names<T>'.ts(2345)
        this.baz("asdf"); // Argument of type '"asdf"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Names<T>'.ts(2345)
        this.baz("qwerty"); // Argument of type '"qwerty"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Names<T>'.ts(2345)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're not using just `keyof` as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/Wo829w); what is your intent with the `X extends A ? keyof X : never;` conditional type?

Comment: @jcalz That's one of the ones I thought I'd tried, but I guess not

Comment: Actually I worked out that I had tried what you said but in my real example it didn't work for some other reasons that didn't appear in this simplified example. But I was able to take this hint and proceed to success. Thanks! @jcalz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the example here, all you'd need to use is [the `keyof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/keyof-types.html#the-keyof-type-operator) directly instead of defining `Names` (or you could define `type Names<X extends A> = keyof X`):

```
interface A {
  asdf: string;
}


class B<T extends A> {
  foo(N: keyof T) {

  }

  baz(n: keyof T) {
    this.foo("asdf"); // ok
    this.foo("qwerty"); // err
    this.foo(n); // ok
  }
}

interface C extends A {
  qwerty: string;
}

class D<T extends C> extends B<T> {
  bar() {
    this.foo("asdf"); // ok
    this.foo("qwerty"); // ok
    this.baz("asdf"); // ok
    this.baz("qwerty"); // ok
    this.baz("blork"); // error
  }
}
```

This compiles with no error, as desired.

---

On the other hand, your definition of `Names<T>` is essentially the same as

```
type AllKeysOf<T> = T extends unknown ? keyof T : never;
```

(except that `Names`'s input is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `A`).  This is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), which splits the input up into its [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members, gets the keys of each member, and puts them back together in a union.  So while `keyof (A | B)` is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the keys from each union member, equivalent to `(keyof A) & (keyof B)`, the type `AllKeysOf<A | B>` is equivalent to the union `(keyof A) | (keyof B)`.  Depending on your use case, this difference might matter.

But conditional types that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, like `Names<T>` inside the bodies of the `B` and `D` classes, are not really evaluated by the compiler.  It *defers* their evaluation and they are therefore *opaque* types.  Inside the `baz()` method of `B<T>`, for example, the compiler has no idea what type `Names<T>` might be, and it errs on the side of rejecting everything.  So while you and I can reason that `"asdf"` must be assignable to `Names<T>` if `T extends A`, the compiler just gives up and complains.  So I'd recommend against using generic conditional types if you don't have to use them: if `keyof T` works, then you should use it instead of `Names<T>`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnLgZwBMYAuZfMKUAcwG4sBfLZhAGwP2QCEAeAFWQQAHpBCFOqAHyYcyGAHt5ACgByZANYQAnvJjI+AShmymsgEZwAXkpAbtu-Uey5cYABbB8AOgXKARATEfga0yAD0Ycjy6rKuHt6+Sn4AjgDu0GBawaERglBQscjunj6KNiHhkdEmjMygkLCIKADCgiIQYhIyuGkZWmQUVCB0tVhsHMgAIvxtouLIzdLCc5y8fNLOyBZQSk6FxQllAUQw2ZVRMS5F8aX+vVCZZ7nVVwdeFtbHQRXPly5vHyS90ePyqfziJUBfjMrHkUHUT0i0CgcJqpkyAAcUKhWKwANLafAAeRg-GkAF59LMOvMAK4gdQgeSpEDIAD8yE0Oj0AjIIAgADdoLQgA)